# Accessing field in Java based on condition

Tags: java, spring, performance, reflection

I have to write a utility method that can get the particular variable value from an Object,
 on evaluating some conditions.

Below are the requirements.

1. if "name" is coming as type call "getName" to get the Value.
2. If "subtype" is coming as type call "getSubType" to get the Subtype Value.

**Current Solution:**

```
       public Object getFieldValue(String type, IDTO dto){
        Method method = dto.getClass().getMethod("get"+createMethodName(type));
        Object returnedObject = method.invoke(dto, null);
        return returnedObject;
     }
```

However, the operations are quite heavy and it is giving performance issues. Is there any alternative that can be chosen or any better way to do this.

Other points:

1. Interface IDTO has all the getter setters declared only. No fields declared in that.

Comment: Maybe try using MethodHandles and cache them all once, so this method would only fetch method handle from name and invoke it

Comment: @GotoFinal Great option. I will definitely check this one.

Answer (score 1):

If you need performance I would suggest to use code generation for the utility method doing the needed access to IDTO objects. Usually this would be integrated into the build. Your generated method could use a well performing switch statement for every 'type', for example:

```
  /**
  * Utility for generic access to IDTO object properties. 
  * GENERATED code, do not change! See template ....
  */
  public Object getFieldValue(String type, IDTO dto){
    switch (type) {
      case "name" :  return dto.getName();
      case "subtype" :  return dto.getSubtype();
      ... 
    }
    // ERROR handling
    throw new RuntimeException("unknown property");
 }
```

To implement your generator code you could use reflection in the same way as you're code above already does. 
For a more extensive usage of that approach I would suggest to introduce a simple template engine, see for example https://freemarker.apache.org

Comment: Good Option, But need to evaluate more.